# Angular 2.0.2 - Error encountered resolving symbol values statically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm also running into the famous error "Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol ", when running i18n. 
I've already done a lot of research, and I'm not using a lambda function. It happens when I add the following import statement to my base module:

```
export const mapsConfig = new LazyMapsAPILoaderConfig();
mapsConfig.apiKey = 'xyz';
// ... below is in import list
BingMapsModule.forRoot(config),
```

I'm using ng2-bingmaps, which I've contributed to as well: https://github.com/youjustgo/ng2-bingmaps

The weird thing is that it does not matter what the JS code is in ng2-bingmaps. If I remove all .js files, I still get the same error! So, it must be something in the ng2-bingmaps core.d.ts which looks like this:

```html
/**
 * ng2-bingmaps - Angular 2 components for Bing Maps
 * @version v0.2.0
 * @link https://github.com/youjustgo/ng2-bingmaps
 * @license MIT
 */
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { LazyMapsAPILoaderConfig } from './services/maps-api-loader/lazy-maps-api-loader';
export * from './directives';
export * from './services';
export declare const NG2_BINGMAPS_PROVIDERS: any[];
/**
 * The ng2-bing-maps core module. Contains all Directives/Services/Pipes
 * of the core module. Please use `BingMapsModule.forRoot(config)` in your app module.
 *
 * @experimental
 */
export declare class BingMapsModule {
    static forRoot(config: LazyMapsAPILoaderConfig): ModuleWithProviders;
}
```

When I just import BingMapsModule (without the forRoot), it works.

I have checked all providers in ng2-bingmaps, and none of them have lambda functions inside the decorators.

My base module definition:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    // browser module, required to load in browser
    BrowserModule, 
    // routing
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    // angular forms
    FormsModule,
    // ng2-bingmaps
    BingMapsModule.forRoot(mapsConfig),
    // ng-bootstrap
    NgbModule,
    // http
    HttpModule,

    // Angulartics2
    // Angulartics2Module.forRoot(),
    // our custom modules for certain parts of our app
    CreateBookingModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [ 
    // all our components
   ],
  bootstrap:    [ ClientApp ],
  providers: [ 
    // our services
    ]
})
```

Comment: show more of your base module. It's tough to get a good understanding of how you're using the `BingMapsModule` in context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I've resolved it, thanks the @peeskillet for the answer.

1. Using an object literal instead of a configuration object.
2. ng2-bingmaps did not contain the required *.metadata.json files; each .d.ts file apparently requires this.

Comment: Hi Boland, I'm encountering the same issue you have with a library i've written for our backend service. Could you elaborate what you meant with *.metadata.json files and how to create them? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @HanChe you just need to run the Angular2 AOT compiler. It will generate those files: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html#!#compile

Comment: so basically in addition to running tsc you run ngc to generate those file and push them together to npm?

Comment: Yes, first run ngc, then tsc :)

Answer (score 3):

> "Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol "

Though I've never seen this error, it sounds like it's referring to this

```
export const mapsConfig = new LazyMapsAPILoaderConfig();
```

If the `mapsConfig` is in the same file as the module you're using it in, there shouldn't be a need to export it. I imagine removing the `export` should solve the error.

Another thing, you probably don't need to create an instance of the config. You could just use an object literal because of TypeScript's structural type system

```
BingMapsModule.forRoot({
  apiKey: 'xyz'
})
```

Generally with "config" objects, this is how you will see it used anyway.

Comment: Thanks, initially I did not export the constant, it was just a try :) I've resolved it, part of the solution is indeed to use an object literal. The other part is that ng2-bingmaps was missing the required .metadata.json files...

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem while using redux reducers with Angular-cli.
Solved it by exporting and wrapping the function in another function in the app module, and then using the exported function:

```js
export function returnMainReducer(){
  return {mainReducer};
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(returnMainReducer())
  ]
```