# Not able to use "angular2-serverpagination-datatable" in my angular 4.2.4 project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to integrate following `"angular2-serverpagination-datatable"` data table module for server side pagination in my angular 4 application but always getting following error after running ng serve:

> "ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
>   Calling function 'makeDecorator', function calls are not supported.
>   Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an
>   exported function, resolving symbol NgModule in
>   /home/bhuvnesh-kumar/Bhuvnesh/Sourcefuse/Proj_ICLP/angular4/scotchy-scotch/node_modules/angular2-serverpagination-datatable/node_modules/@angular/core/src/metadata/ng_module.d.ts,
>   resolving symbol NgModule in
>   /home/bhuvnesh-kumar/Bhuvnesh/Sourcefuse/Proj_ICLP/angular4/scotchy-scotch/node_modules/angular2-serverpagination-datatable/node_modules/@angular/core/src/metadata.d.ts,
>   resolving symbol NgModule in
>   /home/bhuvnesh-kumar/Bhuvnesh/Sourcefuse/Proj_ICLP/angular4/scotchy-scotch/node_modules/angular2-serverpagination-datatable/node_modules/@angular/core/src/core.d.ts,
>   resolving symbol NgModule in
>   /home/bhuvnesh-kumar/Bhuvnesh/Sourcefuse/Proj_ICLP/angular4/scotchy-scotch/node_modules/angular2-serverpagination-datatable/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts,
>   resolving symbol DataTableModule in
>   /home/bhuvnesh-kumar/Bhuvnesh/Sourcefuse/Proj_ICLP/angular4/scotchy-scotch/node_modules/angular2-serverpagination-datatable/lib/DataTableModule.d.ts, resolving symbol DataTableModule in
>   /home/bhuvnesh-kumar/Bhuvnesh/Sourcefuse/Proj_ICLP/angular4/scotchy-scotch/node_modules/angular2-serverpagination-datatable/lib/DataTableModule.d.ts"

**Note**: Following package `"angular2-datatable"` which provide only client side pagination perfectly working in same application

**Package.json**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.6.0",
    "angular2-datatable-serverpagination": "^0.6.3",
    "angular2-serverpagination-datatable": "^1.5.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "install": "^0.11.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },

 "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
```

**Node version - 8.4.0**

**Npm version - 3.10.10**

Comment: please provide more detailed code looking at error it's seems that makeDecorator  function calls are not supported

Comment: may you post your package.json dependencies ?

Comment: @fatemefazli I have updated the question with package.json

Comment: @v8 sagar 
I have integrated following package as suggested but why i am getting this error
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-serverpagination-datatable

Comment: @BHUVNESH KUMAR Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39989083/angular-2-0-2-error-encountered-resolving-symbol-values-statically  or post code by looking at error no one going to help you

Comment: @v8 sagar bro there is no issue with code i just created scratch application with angular cli and integrated this plugin as mentioned .You can also try it in your end and can found the issue.My simple question why i am getting this error on ng serve

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
"angular2-datatable-serverpagination": ">=0.6.3",
"angular2-serverpagination-datatable": ">=1.5.4",
```

instead of

```
"angular2-datatable-serverpagination": "^0.6.3",
"angular2-serverpagination-datatable": "^1.5.4",
```

Change src/tsconfig.app.json like:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": [],
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"] <=== add this
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

hope this solution work.

Comment: @BHUVNESHKUMAR i updated the answer, hope this helps.